# Erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, sintaxe

O código com problema faz o seguinte: Ele faz parte de um sistema de redefinição de senha que estou criando, porem ao coloca-lo dentro de um ECHO obtive alguns problemas que consegui resolver porem este não vejo solução aparente.

```
echo ''
    .$id = $_GET['id']; // Recebendo o valor vindo do link
    $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID = '".$id."'"); // Há variável $resultado faz uma consulta na tabela selecionando somente o registro desejado
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
    {'
    <html><form id="form_Usuario" method="POST" action="updatecomplete.php" >
        <label> Senha: </label> <br />
            <input type="password" name="pass" style="height:30px; width:250px" value="'.md5($linha['Senha']).'\" />
            <input type="submit" value="Alterar Senha" />
    </form></html>
       '}
```

Quando executo o código obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou um ponto e virgula no final da sua string.

```
</form></html>
   '} <--- aqui
```

Para antecipar e facilitar a indentificação de erros de sintaxe, utilize uma IDE ou algum editor de texto com highlight.

O código da pergunta parece querer fazer uma edição, logo apenas um registro apenas é retornado, não é necessário o while, porém formatar o html e imbutirr o php nele é importante para não criar um código bagunçado.

Não coloque variáveis direto na instrução SQL, isso torna seu código vulneravel a sqlinjections, resolve isso com prepared statements.

```
<?php
    $id = !empty($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $registro = $result->fetch_assoc();
 ?>   

<html>
    <form id="form_Usuario" method="POST" action="updatecomplete.php" >
        <label> Senha: </label> <br />
        <input type="password" name="pass" style="height:30px; width:250px" value="<?php echo md5($registro['Senha']); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Alterar Senha" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento de boa, a resposta tem algum problema? posso melhorar

Comment: Desculpem pelos sérios erros que cometi mas estou no começo do meu curso em php e sql, esse formulário era bem simples mesmo apenas para aprender a lidar melhor com o php inclusive nem usei o css. Sobre o echo no começo usei porque tinha feito um if que verificava se um hash gerado e um e-mail estava correto e caso não exibiria um erro e caso existisse executaria este código então pelo que tinha lido deu a entender que era obrigatório o uso do echo. Muito obrigado por esclarecer minha dúvida fiz algumas alterações no código e no final deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 2):

Pra exibir html junto ao php deve usar `echo` ou:

```
?> seu html aqui <?php
```

Assim:

```
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
?>
<html><form id="form_Usuario" method="POST" action="updatecomplete.php" >
    <label> Senha: </label> <br />
        <input type="password" name="pass" style="height:30px; width:250px" value="<?php echo md5($linha['Senha']); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Alterar Senha" />
</form></html>
<?php
}
```

Provavelmente teve problemas por que aqui você tentou "escapar" o quote (`"`) sem necessidade, use assim se for usar o echo:

```
echo ''
    .$id = $_GET['id']; // Recebendo o valor vindo do link
    $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID = '".$id."'"); // Há variável $resultado faz uma consulta na tabela selecionando somente o registro desejado
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
    {

    echo '<html><form id="form_Usuario" method="POST" action="updatecomplete.php" >
        <label> Senha: </label> <br />
            <input type="password" name="pass" style="height:30px; width:250px" value="' . md5($linha['Senha']) . '" />
            <input type="submit" value="Alterar Senha" />
    </form></html>';
    }
```

Recomendo que aprenda o básico do seguindo a documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php